# Transfer website to a wordpress blog retaining the older links and RSS feeds

Tags: wordpress, rss, blogs

I have around 40 pages on my website. I also have a Wordpress blog.  I would like to shift my website to this blog. When I transfer the website to the blog, I want to transfer its pages to the blog as pages and not blog posts. Would that be possible.

The existing pages on the website have the URLs like;

```
www.xyz.com/article1.htm
www.xyz.com/article2.htm
www.xyz.com/article3.htm
```

When I create a blog, I want these links to be redirected to new links on the blog, like:
`www.xyz.com/article1.htm` should redirect to  `www.newblog.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/article1.htm`

`www.xyz.com/article2.htm` should redirect to `www.newblog.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/article2.htm`

`www.xyz.com/article3.htm` should redirect to `www.newblog.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/article3.htm` and so on.

How can I do this?

Also could existing RSS feeds to the current blog, be updated/migrated or redirected after this transfer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend the redirection plugin for this.

It's quick and easy to use and manages everything inside the WordPress admin.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

This is one we're using and it seems to do a pretty good job :)

http://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Cheers!